# Why does schedutil use irq_work_queue instead of directly calling kthread_queue_work?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am currently working on a cpufreq governor based on schedutil. I do not understand why `sugov_deferred_update` uses `irq_work_queue` to issue an interrupt which then uses `kthread_queue_work` to queue work on a kernel thread. Couldn't `sugov_deferred_update` simply directly call `kthread_queue_work`? As far as I understand `irq_work_queue` main purpose is to interact with the system out of a NMI context. However in this case the code is not executed in such a context. So what is the reason to use this construct?